# Trying to HeapSort while using buildheap

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, heapsort

I am trying to heapsort while using my buildheap but for some reason my function is not working. It works if I don't but the code in my HeapSort function outside of the function but not when it is inside. I don't know how to implement by creating a HeapSort function

```
class BinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heapList = [0]
        self.currentSize = 0
    def percUp(self,i):
        while i // 2 > 0:
          if self.heapList[i] < self.heapList[i // 2]:
             tmp = self.heapList[i // 2]
             self.heapList[i // 2] = self.heapList[i]
             self.heapList[i] = tmp
          i = i // 2
    def insert(self,k):
      self.heapList.append(k)
      self.currentSize = self.currentSize + 1
      self.percUp(self.currentSize)
    def percDown(self,i):
      while (i * 2) <= self.currentSize:
          mc = self.minChild(i)
          if self.heapList[i] > self.heapList[mc]:
              tmp = self.heapList[i]
              self.heapList[i] = self.heapList[mc]
              self.heapList[mc] = tmp
          i = mc
    def minChild(self,i):
      if i * 2 + 1 > self.currentSize:
          return i * 2
      else:
          if self.heapList[i*2] < self.heapList[i*2+1]:
              return i * 2
          else:
              return i * 2 + 1
    def delMin(self):
      retval = self.heapList[1]
      self.heapList[1] = self.heapList[self.currentSize]
      self.currentSize = self.currentSize - 1
      self.heapList.pop()
      self.percDown(1)
      return retval
    def buildHeap(self,alist):
      i = len(alist) // 2
      self.currentSize = len(alist)
      self.heapList = [0] + alist[:]
      while (i > 0):
          self.percDown(i)
          i = i - 1

    def HeapSort(alist): 
        bh = BinHeap()
        bh.buildHeap(alist)
        while bh.currentSize != 0:
            print(bh.delMin())

te = [9,5,6,2,3]                    
print(HeapSort(te))
```

Comment: I see why you added the dummy at 0, but you really should get comfortable with zero based indexes.

Comment: im sorry but what do you mean by this

Comment: The zero, which is in the list but not part of the data, is a "dummy value" because it isn't actual data. (placeholder, fake value, sentinel) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer, you just can't return it?

```
def HeapSort(alist):
    result = []
    bh = BinHeap()
    bh.buildHeap(alist)
    while bh.currentSize != 0:
        result.append(bh.delMin())
    return result
```

If you want it to return a list, just build a list and return it.

Comment: when i do this it tells me that heapsort is not defined.

Comment: Check indentation. You can tell it's defined, but is it in the right scope? Or did your editor try to help out by moving it over a tab, so it's now a member of BinHeap (which it should not be)?